# FormKey current state in flutter equals null

Tags: flutter, dart

So i'm having a form like this:

```
 Form(
                  key: formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        validator: _validateForm,
                        cursorColor: Colors.black,
                        controller: _numberLocalsController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                            hintText: "numero di locali"),
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        validator: _validateForm,
                        cursorColor: Colors.black,
                        controller: _numberRoomsController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                            hintText: "numero stanze da letto"),
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        validator: _validateForm,
                        cursorColor: Colors.black,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        controller: _numberbathroomsController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                            hintText: "n° bagni"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
```

and i initialized the formKey outside the build method like this :

```
class _FilterPageState extends State<FilterPage> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();}
```

The idea is that there's a button that's clicked that just does the following :

```
final isValid = formKey.currentState.validate();
                  if (isValid) {
        
                    Navigator.pop(context, filterModel);
                  }
```

Now I get the error

> Validate() was called on null

The formkey current context only has a value the first time i open the form. but when the navigator pops and i try to access the form again it gives the error.

Comment: Can you post your full State widget?

Comment: When you say "access the form again" do you mean calling `formKey.currentState.validate()` from a previous page or `Navigator.push()` back to the `FilterPage` where `formKey` is defined and you still see error ?

Comment: So the scenario is the following. i call formKey.currentState.validate() and then call Navigator.pop() and if i try to call Navigator.push() which brings me back to the filterPage the issue occurs @Baker

Comment: I am also facing the same error have you found out the solution

Answer (score -1):

Salma,

I'm still not clear on where / why you're seeing the null error, since I don't have access to your full code.

So I'll just post my own code sample below and you can compare implementations and hopefully that leads you to an answer.

From my test code below, it should be possible to `Navigator.pop` from the form page back to a previous page and then `Navigator.push` back to the form page and use the formKey again, without a null error.

**FormStateTestPage**

- Just a base page with a Scaffold

**BasePage**

- StatefulWidget where you can click a button to `Navigator.push` to the form page (`FilterPage`).

**FilterPage**

- the `Form` is here
- with the code sample below the `Form` is using a locally defined form key (`localKey`)
- you can `push` to this FilterPage, `pop` back to `BasePage`, and `push` again to `FilterPage` and there should be no null errors
- if you need access to form state *outside* of `FilterPage`, then you must declare a form key **above** `FilterPage` and provide it as a constructor argument
- for outside access, replace the `foreignKey: null` with `foreignKey: foreignKey` (which is defined in `_BasePageState`).  Then you can access form state from `BasePage`.
- the code below is capturing the return value from the `Navigator.push / Navigator.pop` to `FilterPage` & back.  That is how the form value is being shown in `BasePage`. The key line is: `nukeCodes = await Navigator.push<String>`
- if `nukeCodes` is not null after popping back to BasePage, a setState is called, rebuilding BasePage & displaying the `nukeCodes` value.

```
class FormStateTestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Form State Test'),
      ),
      body: BasePage(),
    );
  }
}

class BasePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BasePageState createState() => _BasePageState();
}

class _BasePageState extends State<BasePage> {
  Key foreignKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String nukeCodes;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text('Nuke Codes:'),
        Text(nukeCodes ?? 'awaiting'),
        Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Go to Form'),
            onPressed: () async {
              nukeCodes = await Navigator.push<String>(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => FilterPage(foreignKey: null)
                ) // pass null to have FilterPage use its own, self-defined formKey
                // pass in foreignKey to use a formKey defined ABOVE FilterPage
              );
              if (nukeCodes != null && nukeCodes.isNotEmpty) {
                print('Codes returned');
                setState(() {});
              }
            }
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class FilterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> foreignKey;

  FilterPage({this.foreignKey});

  @override
  _FilterPageState createState() => _FilterPageState();
}

class _FilterPageState extends State<FilterPage> {
  final localKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.foreignKey != null) {
      formKey = widget.foreignKey;
      print('Form using foreignKey');
    }
    else {
      formKey = localKey;
      print('Form using localKey');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String codes;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          //key: widget.formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Nuclear Codes'
                ),
                onSaved: (val) => codes = val,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'A value is required';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Submit'),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    formKey.currentState.save();
                    Navigator.pop(context, codes);
                  }
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Anyways, hopefully you can compare/contrast your code base with above and find out what's causing the null error.

Best of luck.